# Infimum of $\left\{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}}, n, m \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

I am trying to find infimum of $\Big\{\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}}, \quad n, m \in \mathbb{N}\Big\}$

First, by using **geometric mean** $\leq$ **arithmetic mean**, I get:
$$\sqrt[n]{m} = \sqrt[n]{m \cdot 1^{n-1}} \leq \frac{m + (n - 1)}{n} \qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\sqrt[m]{n} = \sqrt[m]{n \cdot 1^{m-1}} \leq \frac{n + (m - 1)}{m} \qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
now I invert:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}} \geq \frac{n}{m + (n - 1)} \qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}} \geq \frac{m}{n + (m - 1)} \qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
and sum both sides:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}}\geq \frac{n + m}{m + n - 1} \qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
conclude that $n + m > n + m - 1$ for $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}}\geq \frac{n + m}{m + n - 1} > 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}} > 1\qquad n, m \in \mathbb{N}$$
How do I prove that $1$ is the greatest lower bound?

Edit (thanks to first comment):
Now to prove that it's the greatest bound, by taking any $\epsilon > 0$ and proving that:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad\exists_{m, n \in \mathbb{N}}: \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{m}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{n}} > \epsilon + 1$$
Which is, of course, true because for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a natural number $m$ big enough to make the inequality below true for $n = 1$: $$1 + \frac{1}{m} < 1 + \epsilon$$

Comment: What happens if you choose $n=1$ and a laaarge $m$?